# Is it possible to execute a task in microsecond interval in windows with python 2.7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, timer

What is the minimum timer resolution in windows? I need to execute a task or function for every 1ms using python.Whether it is possible to do that?
Whether it is possible to execute a task in microseconds? 
Threading.timer() in python doesn't works well for this problem.Is there any other solution to do this.
In the following code the base timer is 500 microseconds and task1 should be called every 10ms

```
counter = 0
def task1():
    print "Message sent every 10ms"
    dev.send_msg(0x1C0, 0x043103A980000000)

def task():
    global counter
    print "In task"
    counter = counter + 1
    if(counter == 20):
        task1()
        counter = 0
    threading.Timer(0.0005,task).start()

task()
```

Comment: Could you give a code snippet to show where you are using this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your counter from 20 to 40 as 40 * 500us = 10ms

```
counter = 0
def task1():
    print "Message sent every 10ms"
    dev.send_msg(0x1C0, 0x043103A980000000)

def task():
    global counter
    print "In task"
    counter = counter + 1
    if(counter == 20):
        task1()
        counter = 0
    threading.Timer(0.0005,task).start()

task()
```

or just start it every 1ms:
*EDITED*

```
def task1():
    print "Message sent every 10ms"
    dev.send_msg(0x1C0, 0x043103A980000000)

def task():
    task1()
    threading.Timer(0.001,task).start()

task()
```

Comment: The code doesn't work as expected..I tried these things already @hazz303

Comment: What do you actually want to happen? you want task1 to be called every 10 milliseconds right? not 10 microseconds?

Comment: My minimum requirement is execute a task for every 1ms...Whether it is possible to execute a task for every 500 microseconds

Comment: The edited program there will run the function task1 every 1ms. If you want it to run 500 microseconds change the 0.001 to 0.0005